# Amazon ECS: How can I monitor a daemon/worker which is not web based?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

We are planning to run a service on ECS which isn't a webserver, but is a (node.js based) background daemon which we are going to use for processing asynchronous tasks. I wanted to add a health check to it so that the task is restarted in case the daemon dies or gets killed. The [target group health checks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html) only support http and https protocols and probably are not meant for this purpose. Any insights into how I can monitor non web based services on ECS and ensure that it's always up and running?

Comment: Publish a custom metric for environment health to cloudwatch. Create an Alarm based on that metric in Cloudwatch Alarms.

Comment: In a similar situation not related to ECS though, we had used Redis and the  background jobs will keep reporting to redis with a TTL when they are not doing any job. If a TTL is expired and not reset by the daemon then we used to know the job has gone down